# FOR XML EXPLICIT and Precision

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Say I have the following data I want to use in my FOR XML EXPLICIT query:

```
ItemId:  14528097
ProductId:  7575
Revenue:  12.95
PerItemPrice:  12.95
Quantity: 1
```

Now, when I'm writing my query, i get the following output:

```
    <ItemId>14528097</ItemId>
    <ProductId>7575</ProductId>
    <Revenue>12.9500</Revenue>
    <PerItemPrice>1.295000000000000e+001</PerItemPrice>
    <Quantity>1.000000000000000e+000</Quantity>
```

Is there any way to get it so that it looks like this:

```
    <ItemId>14528097</ItemId>
    <ProductId>7575</ProductId>
    <Revenue>12.9500</Revenue>
    <PerItemPrice>12.95</PerItemPrice>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
```

Or am I out of luck?

Comment: What data type are you using for PerItemPrice and Revenue? If you are using REAL or FLOAT perhaps you could try DECIMAL instead...

Comment: Good point.  I'm currently using a CTE to pre-load some of the stuff; I'll try some explicit casting and post back shortly.

Comment: That worked like a charm; you want to post a quick answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a1ex07 beat me to the answer, but I suspected that you were using `FLOAT` or `REAL` (either intentionally or inadvertently) and I suggest using `DECIMAL` always for numeric values that don't explicitly need the properties of `FLOAT`/`REAL`.

Answer (score 0):

This query works fine, so make sure you have your types correctly casted:

```
declare @t table (
    ItemId varchar(10),
    ProductId varchar(5),
    Revenue decimal(9,2),
    PerItemPrice decimal(9,2),
    Quantity int)

insert into @t select '14528097','7575',12.95,12.95,1

select 1 as 'Tag', NULL as 'Parent', 
    NULL as 'Items!1!',
    NULL as 'Item!2!Item',
    NULL as 'Item!2!Revenue'
union
select 2, 1, NULL, ItemId, Revenue
from @t for xml explicit
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrast the result of using a float column versus a decimal column.

Float...

```
create table #testfloat (a float)
insert into #testfloat values (1)
select * from #testfloat for xml auto
drop table #testfloat

<a="1.000000000000000e+000"/>
```

And now with a decimal type...

```
create table #testdec (a decimal(5,2))
insert into #testdec values (1)
select * from #testdec for xml auto
drop table #testdec

<a="1.00"/>
```